# How to send a mock HTTP request with $httpBackend module using angular-mock.js

Tags: angularjs

I have a short question about a specific case that I explained below:

I created a HTTP GET route with $httpBackend module. The code snippet is given below:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/watchdata').respond(function(method,url,data) {
    console.log("Getting phones");
      return [200, {"hede": "hodo"}, {}];
  });
```

Later on, I send a $http get request to this route. The snippet is provided as follows:

```
$http.get('/watchdata').success(function(data) {
          console.log("I get the watch data.");
        });
```

When I send this HTTP GET request, I face with this error:

```
GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/watchdata 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

What shall be the problem?

The JSFiddle of this problem is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yaprak/A8yq5/1/).